# Kotlin Annotation processor how to get constructor argument types?

Tags: kotlin, annotations

I'm writing an annotation processor in Kotlin and I want to get types of constructor arguments.

Here is my annotated class

```
@SomeAnnotation
class MyClass(name: String, age: Int)
```

Can I extract the `String` and the `Int` types from `annotatedElement.kotlinMetadata`? Or should I just use the `annotatedElement` which is a `TypeElement`? How can I do this?

This is where I'm stucked:

```
val metadata = annotatedElement.kotlinMetadata as KotlinClassMetadata
val proto = metadata.data.classProto
val mainConstructor = proto.constructorList.find { it.isPrimary }
val parameters = annotatedElement.typeParameters
```

The `typeParameters` return 0 and I should have 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code:

1. You are getting generic `typeParameters` instead of `parameters.map { it.type }`
2. You are trying to get **constructor** parameters, but you are using `annotatedElement` instead of `mainConstructor`

Here is how you can correct them:

```
mainConstructor?.parameters?.map { it.type }
```